# Module not found (Typescript and baseUrl option)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, module

I am trying to use custom paths in my typescript project, the problem is that webpack doesn't recognize my modules giving me the *"webpackMissingModule"* error.

I have tried different solutions but nothing works for me. Suggestions? Ideas?

**Some packages**

```
"react": "^16.8.4",
"react-dom": "^16.8.4",
"typescript": "3.3.1",
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"],
  "extends": "./paths.json"
}
```

**paths.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**.env**

```
NODE_PATH=./
```

**Component**

```
import React from "react";
import Hello from "@components/Hello";

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <Hello />
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I found something that worked for me. It's called
[tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin). All you need to do is to import it in your webpack config, connect with the tsconfig.json, and that's all.

The plugin is added in the `resolve.plugins` array of the exported config, **not** `plugins` in the root.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was changing `tsconfig.json` as following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
   }
}
```

All else failed.

Comment: Doesn't webpack have to know how to resolve the url after the generating the output? How does it know to do that without some kind of plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with @icefire approach.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
   }
}
```

and it seems it is the only working solution i got.